# Executor Service started from Servlet Threads

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, spring-mvc

I am creating Executor in a web project so that the callable can do the work after the response has gone back to the web. Work that callable is doing behind the scene is not required for the current page but for one the pages that will follow.

As far as I know when then the response goes back to the web the servlet thread is free to process another request. In this case although the servlet thread created a executor service it should be available to process another incoming request as soon as the response is sent back even if the callables are active. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new thread, which it sounds like you are, then you are correct.  The thread handing the Servlet request goes back in the pool and is free to return results and take the next request.